# Is it possible with CSS only, without hardcoded numbers, to have the same computed value as another element?

Tags: css

Good day, I believe that this is not possible, but asking to be shure. I do not know how to DuckDuckGo similar questions, and I have an example:

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div>xxx</div>
    <div>xxx</div>
    <div>xxx</div>
</div>

<div class='wrapper'>
    With CSS only: how to have this element the same height, without hardcode?
</div>
```

Maybe I can wrap this to table (or display as a table) where the height of one row with, say, 5 children will be the same as height of another row with 9 children? I need this for table data representation where I can have empty rows - I need to have them the same height as another rows with data. Looks like now I will need to use Javascript to get computed height :(

Comment: Try using a `flex` container

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă how is this possible with `flex`?

Comment: No, this is not possible. CSS works on selectors...it can't calculate properties derived values and apply them to another element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS grid can do it:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-rows:1fr; /* The magic property */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div>xxx</div>
    <div>xxx</div>
    <div>xxx</div>
  </div>

  <div class='wrapper'>
    With CSS only: how to have this element the same height, without hardcode?
  </div>
</div>
```